# PHP mysql error when updating database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, syntax, pdo

I'm getting the following error

```
Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: 
Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens
```

When I'm trying to update MySQL database.

Here is the code my using.

```
public function update() {
    global $db;
    $stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE products SET Name='?', Cate_id='?', Price='?', Image='?', Special='?', Special_price='?', Disable='?' WHERE PID = ?;");
    $stmt->execute(array($this->name, $this->category, $this->price, $this->image, $this->special, $this->special_price, $this->disable, $this->id));
}
```

Comment: did you try removing `;` from `"UPDATE products SET Name='?', Cate_id='?', Price='?', Image='?', Special='?', Special_price='?', Disable='?' WHERE PID = ?;"` and running again? i have seen issues caused by `;` while binding the parameters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SET Name='?', Cate_id='?', Price='?', Image='?'  etc
```

does not need quotes in the ?

should be

```
SET Name=?, Cate_id=?, Price=?, Image=? etc...
```

Comment: @meda yeah sorry about that. I was going to do it but it said I have to wait 10 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the following:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE products SET Name='?', Cate_id=?, Price=?, Image=?, Special=?, Special_price=?, Disable=? WHERE PID = ?;");

$stmt->bind_param($this->name, $this->category, $this->price, $this->image, $this->special, $this->special_price, $this->disable, $this->id);

$stmt->execute();
```